# Mudar a cor de uma div com um setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css

Aqui está o codigo:

```js
 
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a.panel').click(function() {
  console.log($($(this).attr('href')));
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));   
            $target.show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);       
    });
});
```

```css
#right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>

<div id="right">
    <div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:blue">
        <script>
            var tmp = new Array("1","2","3","4");
   var myvar;
   var i = 0;
       
   var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(tmp.length) {
     var p= tmp.shift();
     console.log(p);
     document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = p;
    } else {
     clearInterval(timer);
    }
   }, 5000);      
  </script>
    </div>   
</div>
```

O meu objectivo é sempre que aparece uma numero o fundo mude de cor...
Até agora só encontrei funções que o fazem separado.
Já tentei mudar o `click` mas sem resultado.

Comment: Pode utilizar jQuery?

Comment: @Ana, considere colocar o código na questão e não dar um link com o mesmo

Comment: @FelipeAvelar O código dela já usa jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que seja isto que você procura:

```js
var tmp = new Array("1","2","3","4");
var color = new Array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
var myvar;
var i = 0;
       
setInterval(function() {
    $( "#right" ).text(tmp.shift());
    $( "#right" ).css("background-color", color.shift());
}, 5000);
```

```css
#right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="right">
</div>
```

Comment: é mesmo isso, obrigada!

Comment: existe maneira de preservar o efeito de deslizamento para a esquerda sempre que muda de cor? `.css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);`

Answer (score 1):

Aproveitando o exemplo dado, deve ser isto que pretende.

```
<a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>

<div id="right">
    <div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:blue">
        <script>
            var tmp = new Array("1","2","3","4");
            var clr = new Array("red","blue","green","yellow");
            var myvar;
            var i = 0;

            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                if(tmp.length) {
                    var p= tmp.shift();
            var c = clr.shift();
                    console.log(p);
                    document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = p;
document.getElementById("right").style.backgroundColor =  c;
                } else {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }, 500);                 
        </script>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: existe maneira de preservar o efeito de deslizamento para a esquerda sempre que muda de cor? `.css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);`